# Своя карта для сайта

Tags: javascript, framework, map

На сайте нужно реализовать свою карту(статическая картинка) с метками, которые будут двигаться, есть какие-нибудь Framework-и. Хотелось бы чтобы было масштабирование

Comment: *google maps* или *mapbox* к примеру, или такое не устраивает?

Comment: Задайте четкий вопрос , что бы услышать определенный ответ , а так что вам нужно понятно , но за вас никто это делать не будет.